# How to I get Postgresql with clause to work on more than one statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given

```
Create table Person(
    PersonID int Primary Key default nextval('My_seq'),
    PersonName text
)
create table PhoneNumber(
    PhoneNumberID int primary Key default nextval('My_seq'),
    PersonID int,
    PhoneNumber text,
    Label text, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_PersonID
       FOREIGN KEY(PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
)
```

I want to insert a person and their multiple phone numbers all at once to maintain a 1 to 1 or more relationship. I was looking at this:

```
With newRow as (
 insert into person (PersonName) values('Mr. Black') returning PersonID
)
insert into PhoneNumber (PersonID, PhoneNumber, Label) 
  Values((Select PersonID from newRow),'555-1234','Home')
insert into PhoneNumber (PersonID, PhoneNumber, Label) 
  Values((Select PersonID from newRow),'454-1234','Office')
insert into PhoneNumber (PersonID, PhoneNumber, Label) 
  Values((Select PersonID from newRow),'333-1234','Cell')
```

But only the first insert will see Newrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `union all`?

```
With newRow as (
     insert into person (PersonName) values('Mr. Black') returning PersonID
)
insert into PhoneNumber (PersonID, PhoneNumber, Label) 
    select PersonId, '555-1234', 'Home' from newRow union all
    select PersonID, '454-1234', 'Office' from newRow union all
    select PersonID, '333-1234', 'Cell' from newRow;
```